# Does Redis cluster require knowledge of sharding for reads/writes?

Tags: redis, memcached

#### Traditional (regular) redis

From what I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached), when using **memcached**:

- Each client knows all servers
- The servers do **not** communicate with each other
- If a client wishes to set or read the value corresponding to a certain key, the client's library first computes a hash of the key to determine which server to use.

My understanding is that Redis (**not** Redis cluster) imposes the same requirements and logic. That is, clients need to know what servers they need to write data to (e.g. using a hash or equivalent).

#### Redis cluster

With **Redis cluster**, things seem to be different. It looks like:

- Masters talk with each other
- Masters talk with replication slaves

This seems to bring it closer to e.g. `etcd` or `Zookeeper`, except that perhaps it's all in memory (and thus faster for caching).

That said, in `etcd` one can write to **any** node (follower or leader) e.g. a in RR (Round Robin) fashion (i.e. as long as the `etcd` node responds), and **not** have to **know** about how data is **sharded** when reading/writing to the nodes. This is because `etcd` uses a consensus algorithm (Raft) to distribute data across nodes, and the `etcd` tries to write and store **all data** on **all nodes**.

Does this also apply to Redis cluster? Or does one need to know where each key lives (and thus what nodes to hit) when reading/writing to the cluster?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that Redis (not Redis cluster) imposes the same requirements and logic. That is, clients need to know what servers they need to write data to (e.g. using a hash or equivalent).

Not exactly. In this case, there's only one master node, and client always needs to write to master node (writes to replica node will be overwritten when master syncs with replica). Client can read from any node, except that data read from replica might be stale. There's no hash stuff, since each node has a full copy of all data. If you also employ Redis Sentinel, you can get the master and replica node info from Redis Sentinel dynamically. Also Sentinel will do the master failover stuff.

> Does this also apply to Redis cluster? Or does one need to know where each key lives (and thus what nodes to hit) when reading/writing to the cluster?

Client needs to know where each key located on which node. However, client can send the request to any node. If the key requested does not located on this node, the node will response with the key's location info. Then the client can send another request to the correct node.

Normally a decent client library will implement this logic, and end user doesn't need to know these details.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! So to summarize: With **(basic) Redis** the client always writes to a single node, but can in principle read from replicas since **all nodes** in this case would contain the same data (up to a delay). However, with **Redis cluster** things are different and the client needs to ultimately fetch the key from one of the nodes holding the data it's looking for, since not all nodes contain all data. Did I get it right?

Comment: @Josh YES, you got it

Comment: Awesome, thanks! For completeness (in case others see this): in conclusion, for the question the OP title: 1) Yes, data **is** sharded in Redis cluster but not in normal Redis. That said, 2) for Redis cluster the client does **not** need to know ahead of time or remember where the data is exactly hosted.

Comment: @Josh just one thing to add to your summary is that in the cluster scenario, you should be thinking about it as a node group. So the data you're looking for would be stored in one node group, but could still be fetched from the primary or any one of the replica nodes in that group.